# (F)Lex checking symbol without "consuming" it

Tags: string, concatenation, flex-lexer, lex

The purpose of this is to concatenate strings (with (f)lex if possible) if they're written consecutively separated only by whitespace.
Strings start and end with "s.
The thing is I used states and while it can concatenate the strings it also consumes the next character/symbol that comes right after the strings.

For example -- "this " "is only " "1 string"id -- this will concatenate the strings ("this is only 1 string") but it will also "consume" the i in id thus destroying one token.
Is there a way to check the next char/symbol without actually "consuming/disposing" (can't really think of a term) it.

```
\"                     yy_push_state(X_STRING); yylval.s = new std::string("");
<X_STRING>\"           yy_push_state(X_CONC);
<X_STRING>.            yylval.s += yytext;
<X_STRING>\n           yyerror("newline in string");
<X_CONC>[ ^\n]         ;
<X_CONC>\"             yy_pop_state();
<X_CONC>.              yy_pop_state(); yy_pop_state(); return STRING
```

Any way to do it?

Comment: I would do this in the grammar, not the lexer. Much simpler, provided it doesn't add conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yyless(0)` to cause the current token to be rescanned. Make sure you change start condition, or you'll end up with an endless loop.

By the way, I think your code would be more readable if you switched start conditions with BEGIN rather than using the state stack. In fact, you could easily avoid start conditions, but that would make interpreting escape sequences more complicated. Possibly better would be to just avoid X_CONC by using a rule for `\"[[:space:]]*\"`

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly and managed to add a couple of other functionalities. I didn't even think about BEGIN before. (read about it but was about 2 months ago). Also added.